# Which tool to compare an Oracle database with a Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

We are currently migrating an Oracle database 10gR2 to a Postgresql database 9.3.
Thanks to Hibernate, all tables can be recreated seamlessly.

However, the Oracle database is huge. We are going to write a small tool that will bring the data from one db to the other.

We want to check the quality of the migration with some kind of third-party database comparator.

Do you know a tool that can compare an Oracle database and a Postgresql database (schema + data) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the Schema Comparison Tool from [dbsolo](http://www.dbsolo.com/schema_comparison.html). I don't know if you can compare different databases with one another.

You have to keep in mind that Oracle and PostgreSQL have quite different table definition clauses which make it difficult to compare them accurately.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know there is no such tool around. however, you got a couple of choices:
a.) use oracle_fdw and just join the stuff or b.) export data to text files and use a simple UNIX diff. it works like a charm usually.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumble upon another tool capable of this migration: [dbMigration .NET](http://fishcodelib.com/DBMigration.htm).

[image]

Here are some databases supported:

- Oracle
- Postgresql
- SQlite
- SQL Server
- ... (see complete list on the site)

It can be installed with [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dbmigration).

Answer (score 0):

I've recently added support for Oracle to my [KS DB Merge Tools for Cross-DBMS](https://ksdbmerge.tools/for-cross-dbms), PostgreSQL was already supported.

I agree with the accepted answer that it is difficult to compare different DBMS because of different language features and data types. But when we talk about DBMS migration - sometimes it is enough to ensure that our DB exposes the same interface as before - same list of tables with same columns and similar data types, data migration produces the same rows.
This tool introduces the concept of generic data type like number, string and few others. As of today (Jul '23) this tool compares table definition as a set of column generic types, nullability and set of primary key columns. Later I am going to add more - constraints, indexes, etc. And it compares data by comparing column values of the same generic type.
There is a free version available, allowing to compare both table schema and data. You can compare any table vs any other table and apply custom mapping if there were significant changes in objects naming conventions.

[image]

Comment: Please declare your affiliation to the tool.

Comment: @RohitGupta I've mentioned in the answer that the tool is "my". I am the author.